# configure Azure ContainerInstance to use self hosted registry

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I'm currently testing Azure and i tried to deploy my own docker image.
The image is hosted on a registry on my VServer.
The registry is using port 5000.
When I try to provide the .yaml file with proper imageRegistryCredentials it fails.

```
Image registry credentials:
- server: my.server.com:5000
  username: me
  password: abc123
```

az container create -g My group --file myconainer.yaml returns:

```
The server 'my.server.com:5000' in the 'imageRegistryCredentials' of container group 'MyContainerGroup' is Invalid. 
It should be a valid hostname without protocol.
```

And if I do not provide a port I can not login to the registry.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your private registry can be accessed from the Internet? Or just can be accessed inside your private network?

Comment: The registry is public accessible and hosted outside my network by a provider.

Comment: You can try to just add the registry server, without the port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create the Azure container Instance from a private container registry, then the container registry should be accessed from the Internet, at least the Azure can access it, not just can be accessed from the private network.

If not, I suggest you can push your image to [Azure Container Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-intro), then create the Azure container Instance from it. It's also a private registry. And it has great [access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aci).

If you have more questions, please let me know. I'm glad to provide more help.

**Update**

The definition of the property of the [`imageRegistryCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerinstance/2018-10-01/containergroups#imageregistrycredential-object) in the Azure Template, it's also the same means in the yaml file. It does not need the port, just the server name. I can reappear the error you got if add the port.

[image]

Try just add the registry server name without the port like this:

```
apiVersion: 2018-10-01
location: eastus
name: azureContainerGroup
properties:
  containers:
  - name: aci-tutorial-app
    properties:
      image: charlesacr.azurecr.io/nginx:v1
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1
          memoryInGb: 1.5
      ports:
      - port: 80
  osType: Linux
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
    - protocol: tcp
      port: '80'
  imageRegistryCredentials:
    - server: charlesacr.azurecr.io
      username: charlesACR
      password: xxxxxxxxxx
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

**Update-2**

With the test, finally, I find that Azure Container Instance does not support the private registry with certificate currently, it just supports the private registry with username and password. Maybe it will support in the future, but not now. So if you want to use the private registry, then you need to delete the certificate authenticate.

You can always raise your feedback over this link:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the problem is not that azure can not access the server but that i cannot pass the proper login credentials to azure since i cannot provide the port i would like to use to azure.

Comment: @TomBlo If your registry expose with the specific port to the internet?

Comment: @TomBlo Do you try the advice I provide in the comment?

Comment: @TomBlo Any more questions? Does the advice work? Please let me know if there is an update!

Comment: I tested the using the azure registry and removing the port from the servername.
The azure registry worked fine, but this does not really solve the problem, since i would like to use my registry. 
When removing the port azure is not able to connect with following error:
    The image 'my.server.com:5000/myregistry:runner' in container group 
    'MyGroup' is not accessible. Please check the image and 
     registry credential.

Comment: @TomBlo I make the update and you can take a look. Although it's not a good result, that's the truth.